# LSM6DS3 with madgewick flter to find tilt angle, problems with accelerometer output

Tags: arduino, sensor-fusion

I am trying to find the tilt angle of an object using LSM6DS3 in  arduino mega board, using Madgwick filter algorithm. But the accelero meter values drops suddenly to zero readings, so that the filter gives error output. Attaching my codes with this post.

```
/* Sensor SDI/SDA - Arduino  Digital Pin 51 or MOSI (Master Out Slave In)
 * Sensor SCK/SCL - Arduino  Digital Pin 52 or SCK (Serial Clock)
 * Sensor SDO/ADR - Arduino  Digital Pin 50 or MISO (Master In Slave Out)
* Sensor CS - Arduino  Digital Pin 10 or 53 (Slave Select or Chip Select)
*/

#include <SPI.h>          // Include Arduino SPI library
#include <math.h>

#define OUT_X_L_G   0x22  // Register addresses from sensor datasheet.
#define OUT_X_H_G   0x23  // Only the registers that are used
#define OUT_Y_L_G   0x24  // in this program are defined here.
#define OUT_Y_H_G   0x25
#define OUT_Z_L_G   0x26
#define OUT_Z_H_G   0x27
#define CTRL1_A     0x10
#define CTRL2_G     0x11
#define CTRL3_C     0x12
#define CTRL4_C     0x13
#define CTRL9_A     0x18
#define CTRL10_C    0x19
#define OUT_X_L_A   0x28
#define OUT_X_H_A   0x29
#define OUT_Y_L_A   0x2A
#define OUT_Y_H_A   0x2B
#define OUT_Z_L_A   0x2C
#define OUT_Z_H_A   0x2D
#define WHO_AM_I   0x0F
#define CTRL7_G    0x16  // setting hpf for gyro
#define STATUS_REG 0x1E

#define sampleFreq   512.0f          // sample frequency in Hz 512
#define betaDef         0.1f            // 2 * proportional gain 0.1

#define M_PI 3.14


int8_t readData   = 0x80;
int8_t writeData  = 0x00;

int8_t k ;

int16_t Ax, Ay, Az;       // 16-bit variables to hold raw data from sensor
int16_t Gx, Gy, Gz;

float Aax, Aay, Aaz;      
float Ggx, Ggy, Ggz;



const int CS = 53;        // Chip Select pin for SPI



void MadgwickAHRSupdateIMU(float gx, float gy, float gz, float ax, float ay, float az);

  volatile float beta = betaDef;
  volatile float q0 = 1.0f, q1 = 0.0f, q2 = 0.0f, q3 = 0.0f;
  float invSqrt(float x);
  float roll,pitch;





void setup()
{


  Serial.begin(57600);
  SPI.begin();
  SPI.setClockDivider(SPI_CLOCK_DIV4);
  SPI.setBitOrder(MSBFIRST);
  SPI.setDataMode(SPI_MODE3);

  pinMode(CS, OUTPUT);

  writeReg(CTRL3_C, 0x40);  // BDU UPDATE
  delay(100);

  writeReg(CTRL9_A, 0x38); // Enable x,y,z axes of ACCEL
  writeReg(CTRL10_C, 0x38); //Enable x,y,z of GYRO
  writeReg(CTRL1_A, 0x7C);  // ODR=833, scale = 8g
  writeReg(CTRL2_G, 0x7C); // scale= =2000dps, ODR = 833
  writeReg(CTRL4_C, 0x04); // SPI only, I2C disabled 
  writeReg(CTRL7_G, 0x70);  // setting high pass  filter for gyro
 delay(100);
}



void loop() 
{
  Gx = (int16_t) readReg(OUT_X_H_G) <<8 | readReg(OUT_X_L_G); // typecast as
  Gy = (int16_t) readReg(OUT_Y_H_G) <<8 | readReg(OUT_Y_L_G); // 16-bit
  Gz = (int16_t) readReg(OUT_Z_H_G) <<8 | readReg(OUT_Z_L_G);
  Ax = (int16_t) readReg(OUT_X_H_A) <<8 | readReg(OUT_X_L_A);
  Ay = (int16_t) readReg(OUT_Y_H_A) <<8 | readReg(OUT_Y_L_A);
  Az = (int16_t) readReg(OUT_Z_H_A) <<8 | readReg(OUT_Z_L_A);

  Aax = (Ax*0.244)/1000;
  Aay = (Ay*0.244)/1000;
  Aaz = (Az*0.244)/1000;

  Ggx = (Gx*0.07)*(M_PI/180);
  Ggy = (Gy*0.07)*(M_PI/180);
  Ggz = (Gz*0.07)*(M_PI/180);

  MadgwickAHRSupdateIMU( Ggx, Ggy,  Ggz, Aax,Aay,Aaz);


  roll=atan2(2*q2*q3-2*q0*q1,(2*q0*q0)+(2*q3*q3)-1)*180/M_PI;
  pitch=-1*asin(2*q1*q3+2*q0*q2)*180/M_PI;

  Serial.println(roll);

  Serial.println(pitch);


}





int8_t readReg(int8_t address) {
  int8_t buffer = 0;
  digitalWrite(CS, LOW); 
  SPI.transfer(readData | address);
  buffer = SPI.transfer(writeData);
  digitalWrite(CS, HIGH);
  return(buffer);  
  }

 void writeReg(int8_t address, int8_t val)

 {
  digitalWrite(CS, LOW);
  SPI.transfer(writeData | address);
  SPI.transfer(val);
  digitalWrite(CS, HIGH);
}



void MadgwickAHRSupdateIMU(float gx, float gy, float gz, float ax, float ay, float az) 
{
float recipNorm;
float s0, s1, s2, s3;
float qDot1, qDot2, qDot3, qDot4;
float _2q0, _2q1, _2q2, _2q3, _4q0, _4q1, _4q2 ,_8q1, _8q2, q0q0, q1q1,  q2q2, q3q3;
// Rate of change of quaternion from gyroscope
qDot1 = 0.5f * (-q1 * gx - q2 * gy - q3 * gz);
qDot2 = 0.5f * (q0 * gx + q2 * gz - q3 * gy);
qDot3 = 0.5f * (q0 * gy - q1 * gz + q3 * gx);
qDot4 = 0.5f * (q0 * gz + q1 * gy - q2 * gx);
// Compute feedback only if accelerometer measurement valid (avoids NaN in     accelerometer normalisation)
if(!((ax == 0.0f) && (ay == 0.0f) && (az == 0.0f))) {
// Normalise accelerometer measurement
recipNorm = invSqrt(ax * ax + ay * ay + az * az);
ax *= recipNorm;
ay *= recipNorm;
az *= recipNorm;
// Auxiliary variables to avoid repeated arithmetic
_2q0 = 2.0f * q0;
_2q1 = 2.0f * q1;
_2q2 = 2.0f * q2;
_2q3 = 2.0f * q3;
_4q0 = 4.0f * q0;
_4q1 = 4.0f * q1;
_4q2 = 4.0f * q2;
_8q1 = 8.0f * q1;
_8q2 = 8.0f * q2;
 q0q0 = q0 * q0;
 q1q1 = q1 * q1;
 q2q2 = q2 * q2;
 q3q3 = q3 * q3;
 // Gradient decent algorithm corrective step
 s0 = _4q0 * q2q2 + _2q2 * ax + _4q0 * q1q1 - _2q1 * ay;
 s1 = _4q1 * q3q3 - _2q3 * ax + 4.0f * q0q0 * q1 - _2q0 * ay - _4q1 + _8q1 *     q1q1 + _8q1 * q2q2 + _4q1 * az;
 s2 = 4.0f * q0q0 * q2 + _2q0 * ax + _4q2 * q3q3 - _2q3 * ay - _4q2 + _8q2 *    q1q1 + _8q2 * q2q2 + _4q2 * az;
 s3 = 4.0f * q1q1 * q3 - _2q1 * ax + 4.0f * q2q2 * q3 - _2q2 * ay;
 recipNorm = invSqrt(s0 * s0 + s1 * s1 + s2 * s2 + s3 * s3); // normalise    step magnitude
s0 *= recipNorm;
s1 *= recipNorm;
s2 *= recipNorm;
s3 *= recipNorm;
 // Apply feedback step
qDot1 -= beta * s0;
qDot2 -= beta * s1;
qDot3 -= beta * s2;
qDot4 -= beta * s3;
}
 // Integrate rate of change of quaternion to yield quaternion
q0 += qDot1 * (1.0f / sampleFreq);
q1 += qDot2 * (1.0f / sampleFreq);
q2 += qDot3 * (1.0f / sampleFreq);
q3 += qDot4 * (1.0f / sampleFreq);
// Normalise quaternion
 recipNorm = invSqrt(q0 * q0 + q1 * q1 + q2 * q2 + q3 * q3);
q0 *= recipNorm;
q1 *= recipNorm;
q2 *= recipNorm;
q3 *= recipNorm;
}


float invSqrt(float x)
{
 float halfx = 0.5f * x;
 float y = x;
 long i = *(long*)&y;
 i = 0x5f3759df - (i>>1);
 y = *(float*)&i;
 y = y * (1.5f - (halfx * y * y));
 return y;
 }
```